# Phonegap push notifications with MQTT (background service?)

Tags: cordova, push-notification, push, mqtt

I'm developing an mobile app, with Phonegap*, that's connected to a webservice.
We need to "push" events from the webservice to the app to notify the user.

As it's now we've setup the webservice/app to use MQTT, and it runs smoothly (with restrictions to topics etc).

The problem is, of course, when the app isn't running/active. I'd prefer to use MQTT for this too. But I so far, my research have come up very thin.

I know that there's GCM, APN etc. But:

1. I don't want to mess with a bunch of different external systems.
2. Most messages (some will be "broadcasts" to a group) will be user specific. To me it seems like it will be a PITA to manage that with different delivering systems (MQTT excels here and is pretty straight forward).
3. Some of the data might be considered sensitive.

One solution to #3 would be to deliver a "Hey! You have data!" message, and then let the regular logic collect the data (even if that has it's problems!).

So, some suggestions would be highly welcomed!

(*Right now, it's the only viable solution, I'm currently the only developer and I'm developing both the web service and the app [and the resources are very limited]. To develop native apps for each platform would be impossible as the situation is).

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you will have to use APN to wake the app up and start the MQTT client as current Playstore rules only allow VoIP apps to have long running background tasks.

So you are going to have to develop this capability for Apple devices anyway, so may as well use it for all platforms. This means all the code should be the same as codorva should abstract out the GCM & APN.